# Tooltip catcher

Tags: copy-paste, tooltip

Is there any software with the following features:

- It could be used to copy the tooltip text.
- For example, if I point mouse to button (say in Adobe Photoshop, it will display a long text). Then if I press a key combination, I could get the tool tip which has shown before.

Comment: why can't we built one ??? ;)

Comment: @Sreekumar: We can. I will... or We will... If one exist, we are wasting our precious time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"When in doubt, use brute force."

The tooltip text will be saved somewhere, with a good chance of that being in the executable that displays it.

You can extract strings from the executable in question, e.g. with a utility like [Strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439) (Microsoft) and search the output for a word or two from the displayed tooltip.

> Usage: strings.exe [-a] [-b bytes] [-n
>   length] [-o] [-q] [-s] [-u]
>
> Strings takes wild-card expressions
>   for file names, and additional command
>   line parameters are defined as
>   follows:
>
> `-s`  Recurse subdirectories.
>   `-o`  Print offset in file string is located.
>   `-a`  Scan for ASCII only.
>   `-u`  Scan for UNICODE only.
>   `-b bytes`    Bytes of file to scan.
>   `-n X`    Strings must be a minimum of X characters in length.
>
> **To search one or more files for the
>   presence of a particular string using
>   strings use a command like this:**
>
> `strings * | findstr /i TextToSearchFor`

Answer (score 3):

This is heavily specific to the program you're using. Some programs will just hide the tooltip as soon as you press a key like <kbd>alt</kbd>. So using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> will not work to capture these tooltips. However pressing <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> only usually captures the whole screen including all the tooltips as they appear on the screen.

Some screenshot applications also allow to define global hotkeys. As long as you don't use a key combination it might work even to assign tasks like "caputure window" to these keys.

I recently stumbled upon [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) which also allows definition of hotkeys. So if you want ot capture screen regions only try assigning the <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> key to the region capture action.

Alternatively try just to press <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> (without any screenshot tool running), then pasting your screenshot into a grapics tool (like IrfanView or use Photoshop as you seem to own one). Then cut the area you would like to keep.

Comment: I dont want it as an image, I want it as pure text, need to reuse it.

Comment: OK, this is a different story then. It was not clear to me when reading the question. My aplolgize. Maybe a tool similar to the one included in AutoIt (AutoIt Window Info) could be used to fetch the RAW text from elements appearing on screen. I have tried AutoIt Window Info but it also does not allow to hover over QuickInfo pop-ups because they will disappear as soon as the mouse leaves the button. Maybe some code could be re-used as the QuickInfo text is usually bound to a button. So it might be readable from button properties.